# R - convert WKB geometry to WKT representation

Tags: r, geometry, wkt, wkb

Does anyone knows a package/function in R that takes Well-Known Binary (WKB) as an input, and returns it's Well-Known Text (WKT) representation?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide any reproducible example with code and data, but I think this code can help you.

```
library(rgdal)
library(wkb)
library(rgeos)

wkb <- readBin("geometry.wkb", what = "raw", n = 1000)
wkb <- list(wkb)
writeWKT(readWKB(wkb))
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your code and I get an error that only little endian is supported. Is there anyway I can do that with big endians WKBs?

Comment: @Yoav You are right `readWKB` read only little endian for the time being but let me think about it may be we can figure another solution. However, having the data or similar data could be great for testing

Comment: Thanks alot, here's an example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

Comment: It should be converted to: MULTIPOLYGON (((-86.03970199999999 43.562034999999995, -86.03788399999999 43.815611, -85.562439 43.815633999999996, -85.56253799999999 43.294270999999995, -85.312376 43.294205, -85.312513 43.118793, -84.836889 43.118851, -84.837085 42.770478999999995, -85.07424499999999 42.770784, -85.071609 42.421428, -87.04004599999999 42.416993, -87.020433 42.500032, -87.146587 43.375005, -87.14033099999999 43.471436, -86.039491 43.467447, -86.03970199999999 43.562034999999995)))

Comment: `readWKB` now supports reading big-endian WKB, and there is a new function `hex2raw`in the wkb package that converts string hex representations to raw vectors that can be inputted to `readWKB`.

Comment: @ianmcook Thanks Ian, this is a wonderful news and thanks again for the wkb R package.

Comment: @Yoav Can you update the wkb package and try again please ?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert between WKB and WKT using the packages [rgeos](http://cran.r-project.org/package=rgeos) and [wkb](http://cran.r-project.org/package=wkb). Example:

```
# load packages
library(rgeos)
library(wkb)

# create raw vector representing WKB geometry
wkb <- hex2raw("0101000000cdcccccc170d2241b81e859bcb405241")

# convert WKB to Spatial object
obj <- readWKB(wkb)

# convert Spatial object to WKT
wkt <- writeWKT(obj, byid = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

This article is very intersting:
https://r-spatial.org/r/2016/09/01/bm.html.
This article compare three functions:

1. `sf::st_as_sfc(geometry)`
2. `sf::st_as_sfc(geometry, pureR = TRUE)`
3. `wkb::readWKB(geometry)`

For this article, the faster function to convert wkb to wkt is
`sf::st_as_sfc(geometry)` without the pureR argument.